# Sliding an element lef to right smoothly with jquery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

please look at this fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/rabelais/43J77/1/

```
$('#contact').click(function () {
    $('#contact-info').animate({
        width: 'toggle'
    });
    $('#work-menu').fadeOut('100');
});
$('#menu').click(function () {
    $('#work-menu').animate({
        width: 'toggle'
    });
    $('#contact-info').fadeOut('100');
});
```

When one clicks contact the menu slides smoothly from the side. When one clicks work the menu opens but it doesn't slide like the email element. Does anyone know how to make the work menu slide open like the email element.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/43J77/4/

I changed the `width` of your `#work-menu` and added this `#work-menu ul` style:

```
#work-menu {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 37px;
    left: 65px;
    font-size: 24px;
    width: 183px;  /*changed*/
}
#work-menu ul{  /*added*/
    float:right;
}
```

The difference is that in one of the toggled elements the text is aligned to the left (email) and you are sliding to the left, which causes that effect, and in the other the list is aligned to the left but you are sliding the the right. This way, the text doesn't seem to move, but just to appear.

In order to create the same visual effect I just aligned the list to the right, and in order to do so, I had to define a `width` for the parent element.